# Else statement logic is wacko

Tags: c, if-statement, char, nested-loops, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
   string key_upper = "YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO";
   string key_lower = "ytnshkvefxrbauqzclwdmipgjo";
   string alphabet_upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   string alphabet_lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   string word = "Hello daniel, ! ..";
   char letter_switch[strlen(word)];
   for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
   {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++)
        {
            if (word[j] == alphabet_upper[i])
            {
                letter_switch[j] = key_upper[i];
            }
            else if (alphabet_lower[i] == word[j])
            {
                letter_switch[j] = key_lower[i];
            }
            else 
            {
                letter_switch[j] = word[j];
            }
        }
    }

   for (int k = 0; k < strlen(word); k++)
   {
       printf("%c", letter_switch[k]);
   }
   printf("\n");
    
   return 0;
}
```

I am making a chiper program. It all works perfectly fine if the else statement is defined. SO if I switch the else part with:

```
            else if (word[j] == '!' || word[j] == '.' || word[j] == 
                     ',' || word[j] == ' ')
            {
                letter_switch[j] = word[j];
            }
```

Otherwise it just copies the original word...
Why?

I am doing cs50 so that will probably change some variable definitions and such.

Comment: `string` is what, a `typedef` for `char*`?

Comment: One obvious bug is that you neither allocate room for the null termination nor add one to the final string.

Comment: Also did you actually mean "It all works perfectly fine if the else statement is **not** defined"? Because then it does indeed just copy the original.

Comment: Which version is this? It seems to be a working solution. Please clarify what it is that you don't understand.

Comment: Sorry for not including more details. I changed the question and code now so its maybe a bit more easy to understand my question. The original code does not work. But using the else if statement fixes it.

Comment: @Lundin `string` is a CS50ism that is surely intended to give anyone who also does C++ a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner for loop

```
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++)
    {
        if (word[j] == alphabet_upper[i])
        {
            letter_switch[j] = key_upper[i];
        }
        else if (alphabet_lower[i] == word[j])
        {
            letter_switch[j] = key_lower[i];
        }
        else 
        {
            letter_switch[j] = word[j];
        }
    }
```

the if statements are executed in each iteration of the loop.

So in each iteration of the outer loop if `word[j]` is not equal to the current character `alphabet_upper[i]` or `alphabet_lower[i]` then the else part

```
else 
{
    letter_switch[j] = word[j];
}
```

gets the control. The only case when a letter can be correctly converted is when it is `'z'` or `'Z'` that wll be converted in the last iteration of the outer for loop.

Also the functon `strlen` is called a redundant number of times.

You could esentially simplify the task by means of using standard C functon `strchr`.

For example

```
const size_t N = strlen( word );
char letter_switch[N];

for ( char *current = word, *target = letter_switch; *current != '\0'; ++current, ++target )
{
    char *p;

    if ( ( p = strchr( alphabet_upper, *current ) ) != NULL )
    {
        *target = key_upper[p - alphabet_upper];
    }
    else if ( ( p = strchr( alphabet_lower, *current ) ) != NULL )
    {
        *target = key_lower[p - alphabet_lower];
    }
    else 
    {
        *target = *current;
    }
}

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    putchar( letter_switch[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char *string;

int main( void )
{
    string key_upper = "YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO";
    string key_lower = "ytnshkvefxrbauqzclwdmipgjo";
    string alphabet_upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string alphabet_lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string word = "Hello daniel, ! ..";

    const size_t N = strlen( word );
    char letter_switch[N];

    for (string current = word, target = letter_switch; *current != '\0'; ++current, ++target)
    {
        char *p;

        if (( p = strchr( alphabet_upper, *current ) ) != NULL)
        {
            *target = key_upper[p - alphabet_upper];
        }
        else if (( p = strchr( alphabet_lower, *current ) ) != NULL)
        {
            *target = key_lower[p - alphabet_lower];
        }
        else
        {
            *target = *current;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        putchar( letter_switch[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
Ehbbq syufhb, ! ..
```

Comment: Wow super elaborate! Thank you! Got some tips to make better loops.                             I know my code is inefficient, but I'm still very confused on why adding the else if statement for all the other characters accept letters (which I put as an fix for my code) still works....

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the else, it is the order of your for() loops.
You need to iterate over each letter in the word first, then find which alphabet it is and substitute from your lookup table. If it is not an alphabet, then it has to be copied as-is. There are a lot of ways to do this, but since you seem to be learning, I will show you one with the least changes from your implementation, which would go something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++)
{
    letter_switch[j] = word[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (word[j] == alphabet_upper[i])
        {
            letter_switch[j] = key_upper[i];
        }
        else if (alphabet_lower[i] == word[j])
        {
            letter_switch[j] = key_lower[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And you should break out of the loop after a successful hit...

Comment: I changed my entry a bit. If I use the "else if" it works(So that structure is not affected by the for loop order?), however when using the else statement its my for() loop order?   Thanks you for your answer!

Comment: @SergeBallesta indeed, it's good to add that optimization.

Comment: @Kalle can't be sure until you tell us what the `else if` contains. Of course, like I mentioned, there are quite a few ways to solve this, including without changing the order of the for() loops.

Comment: @th33lf I did add what was inside the else if. And it confuses me like crazy why the else statement wont work and by putting the else if does.